# Static files not found Flask on Apache

Tags: python, apache, flask, http-status-code-404

I have a Flask application deployed on Apache, and the JavaScript files in the `static` folder cannot be found

[image]

I don't understand what is wrong, here are the files:

**Apache conf**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName japanesepractice.local
    ServerAlias www.japanesepractice.local

    WSGIDaemonProcess japanesepractice user=leonardo group=leonardo threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/japanesepractice.local/japanese.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/japanesepractice.local>
        WSGIProcessGroup japanesepractice
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /static/ /var/www/japanesepractice.local/static
    <Directory /var/www/japanesepractice.local/static>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**app.py**:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request

from service import kanjiservice

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

**wsgi file**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

activate_this = '/var/www/japanesepractice.local/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/japanesepractice.local')

from app import app as application
```

**template**:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/responsivevoice.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/speaking.js') }}"></script>
```

Could someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only use an `Alias` for your `/static/` routes if you *don't* want Apache to use your `WSGIScriptAlias` to handle matching requests. This is good for performance, since requests for static files don't need to engage the WSGI application (except creating the URL), but it may be related to your problems.

You can troubleshoot by removing:

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/japanesepractice.local/static
<Directory /var/www/japanesepractice.local/static>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

If removing this works, try re-adding it with balanced trailing slashes (`/static/` as `/static` to match the missing slash `/var/www/japanesepractice.local/static`.

Comment: This is partially correct. I've added my comments below. Your answer was a lifesaver for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
/static
```

not

```
/static/
```

The issue is that all the **apache/debian and ubuntu forums online are incorrect**. Its a major oversight. Logan Bertram above points to the issue as part of his answer.

With this and conda containers using the online tutorials in youtube I was able to expose something that was on localhost:5000 on a public server.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding    `type="text/javascript"`

like below:

```
`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{  url_for('static', filename='js/responsivevoice.js') }}"> . 
</script>`
```